# How to render MediaWiki subpages' titles like the Spanish Wikibooks?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm helping to my job's internal wiki and I find subpages useful for writing pages of a tutorial related to a topic. I understand [how subpages are configured](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Subpages), but when I was reviewing other wikis to see how subpages can be used, I found that the Spanish version of Wikibooks renders the title of the subpages separating each ancestor's title in different lines, instead of one huge title with slashes. [Here is an example](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Gesti%C3%B3n_del_conocimiento/La_aplicaci%C3%B3n_en_la_empresa/Estrategias_de_la_gesti%C3%B3n_del_conocimiento).

How can I achieve that kind of presentation in my wiki? It can be obtained with the default installation? Is a extension needed? Or it is necessary to edit PHP files directly?

Answer (score 2):

It seems it uses a JavaScript gadget called [TitreDeluxe](https://fr.wikibooks.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Gadget-TitreDeluxe.js) (Deluxe Title) from French Wikibooks. It is loaded from [MediaWiki:common.js](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Common.js):

```js
mw.loader.load("//fr.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=MediaWiki:Gadget-TitreDeluxe.js&action=raw&ctype=text/javascript");
```